# Codeigniter + CSS not working well, possible baseurl

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, codeigniter

This question has been asked several times, but I researched and still can't solve it. In one of my view file, I have (referencing to my css):

```
link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="/application/views/screen.css"
```

The css file is in:

```
- www
  - application
    - view
      - css
        - screen.css
  - system
```

I also tried to setup the css in the same folder under `-www` and use it directly by

```
link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="css/screen.css"
```

My base `url` is set to `""` because I develop locally. Is this the issue? I'm Using wamp server.

So what is the problem? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't put your CSS files or files to be served to browser in the application folder as it is protected for security reasons with a .htaccess file set to 'Deny from All' Your CSS, JS, image files etc, need to be outside of the application folder.

Put your CSS file in a folder called 'css' in the 'www' folder so it is NOT inside 'application' or 'system'. Then make sure you use the following (notice the leading slash, denoting an absolute URL):

```
href="/css/screen.css"
```

Use this instead:

```
# If your default controller is something other than
# "welcome" you should probably change this
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: link rel=​"stylesheet" type=​"text/​css" href=​"/​css/​screen.css", doesn't work. And this is what shows up in my Google Chrome using web tool

Comment: This is after you moved the files into a folder called 'css' inside the webroot folder 'www'?

Comment: yes,I have a folder of css under the www folder. and I inspect element and look at the http request header, this is what shows up : h t tp://localhost/css/screen.css

Comment: When you access http://localhost/css/screen.css do you get a 404, 403, 500, etc error?

Comment: re-enable it but comment out these lines # If your default controller is something other than
# "welcome" you should probably change this
RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|files)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

Comment: Your code is exactly what in my rewrite engine. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iEI9J2Ub4gnwmDVYgIeV7Tiig6n1bimRCWlUHBhqyH0/edit this link to a google doc of my rewrite engine. If I sommented out, the css is loaded and works fine but I can't access my other pages

Comment: yeah I know I saw that file, I want you to renable your rewrite file but comment out those lines so can determine if those lines are the ones causing the problem.

Comment: Yes, those lines are causing problems, and I commented out, css is loaded, but other pages doesn't work. So, it is those lines about rewrite engine

Comment: see my edited answer, and replace that section of rewrite rules with that one.

Comment: sorry made some edits, please use current edit. What you were doing was not excluding the folder from redirection and you had multiple rewrite rules for the same thing, so any exclusion for the first rule was being bypassed by the 2nd rule which did not have an exclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Bearing in mind there are several ways to skin a cat.

Quick fix without messing with htaccess.
Use base_url() or site_url():

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/screen.css">
```

And use the following file structure:

- www

  - application

    - views
    - (...)
  - system
  - assets

    - css

      - screen.css

Comment: @cryptic You're actually wrong. As long as the URL helper is loaded base_url() honors it's name and returns well...the base url. Thanks for the downvote anyway.

Comment: Agreed, I prefer this way of doing it, turns the URL into a permanent URL rather than a relative one too and from what I understand that's better SEO wise and saves headaches down the line.

Comment: link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="localhost/assets/css/screen.css" this is what shows up in the browser. and I have the assets folder.

Comment: @AaronSantos If in assests folder I have a JS sub-folder, inside that if I have a file say script.js and I want to call base_url() on that file? Since it gets outside the application folder do you have any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You should put all your asset files (images, js, css etc) into a seperate folder on the root of the site (**outside of the application folder**).
Create a folder called 'files' and add a following line in your `.htaccess` file on the root of the site:

```
# Allow these directories and files to be displayed directly:
# - index.php (DO NOT FORGET THIS!)
# - robots.txt
# - favicon.ico
# - Any file inside of the files/ - js/, or css/ directories
RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|files)
```

This way you will have direct access to that files folder (and any file folder inside) through url.

Comment: I have a folder called css where application is stored and changed rewrite engine. When I typed in ht t p://localhost/assets, it doesn't work, it gives me a 404. By the way, my base_url = ' ' and I am developing locally, if that matters.

Comment: Ok, just to see if I understand you correctly, you have a folder called 'assets' in the root of you localhost, and a 'assets' rewrite condition in your .htaccess file and you still get the 404 error?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iEI9J2Ub4gnwmDVYgIeV7Tiig6n1bimRCWlUHBhqyH0/edit  This is my rewrite engine. Still I can;t access assets folder with url. Under www folder I have -assets, -appliaction, and -system

Comment: Ok, then instead the `RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|files)` line you've added try this line `RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|assets)` and then try to access http://localhost/assets

Comment: still 404 and the url automatically changed form localho st/assets to h t t p ://localhost/assets/?/assets

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the same problem in Windows. In Mac, it was easy thing.
WHen trying to exclude `index.php` from URL, I faced `400 Bad Request Error` .
Later fixed this, by prefixing slash RewriteRule index.php, as below

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

**Going forward, faced another Issue:**
Could not load assets/static files. Also, i had my assets folder at root directory level.
I saw a solution, like adding 'assets' in the RewriteCond to make it get excluded from applying rewriteRule. like,

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets)       #It does not work for me
```

But, it does not work. I got 404 not found error.
Later, i found the solution for this, as

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|\/assets)     #Working!
```

And My Rewrite scripts are here:

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|\/assets)
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Hope, this will help and saves plenty of time! :)